# TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

hoping you could help me with a new and unexpected issue.

Up until yesterday everything was working perfectly fine, then the bot went offline and I logged onto Heroku to check the logs, please see below. I don't have much experience with Python but what I can gather from the logs it seems it must be a discord.py issue. Anyone have any ideas?

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
import giphypop
from discord.ext import commands

key = os.environ['TOKEN']
PREFIX = ">"

#CREATE THE BOT INSTANCE
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, self_bot=True)

###################
# C O M M A N D S #
###################

#@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['g'])
#async def game(ctx, *args):
    #if args:
        #cstatus = ctx.message.server.get_member(bot.user.id).status
        #txt = " ".join(args)
        #await bot.change_presence(game=Game(name=txt), status=cstatus)
        #msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(color=Color.green(), description="Changed game to `%s`!" % txt))
    #else:
        #await bot.change_presence(game=None, status=cstatus)
        #msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(color=Color.gold(), description="Disabled game display."))
    #await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    #await asyncio.sleep(3)
    #await bot.delete_message(msg)


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['s'])
async def status(ctx, *args):
    stati = {
        "on":       Status.online,
        "online":   Status.online,
        "off":      Status.invisible,
        "offline":  Status.invisible,
        "dnd":      Status.dnd,
        "idle":     Status.idle,
        "afk":      Status.idle
    }
    if args:
        cgame = ctx.message.server.get_member(bot.user.id).game
        if (args[0] in stati):
            if (args[0] == "afk"):
                await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=Status.idle, afk=True)
            else:
                await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=stati[args[0]], afk=False)
                print(stati[args[0]])
            msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(description="Changed current status to `%s`." % args[0], color=Color.gold()))
    else:
        await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=Status.online, afk=False)
        msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(description="Changed current status to `online`.", color=Color.gold()))
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await bot.delete_message(msg)
bot.run(key, bot=False)
```

THIS IS THE LOGS

```
2020-07-23T13:08:49.359275+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-23T13:08:49.359440+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
2020-07-23T13:08:49.359799+00:00 app[worker.1]:     bot.run(key, bot=False)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.359803+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360182+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360186+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360490+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return future.result()
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360490+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/client.py", line 491, in start
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360873+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from self.connect()
2020-07-23T13:08:49.360918+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/client.py", line 448, in connect
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361184+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from self.ws.poll_event()
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361226+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/gateway.py", line 431, in poll_event
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361574+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from self.received_message(msg)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361578+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/gateway.py", line 390, in received_message
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361891+00:00 app[worker.1]:     func(data)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.361955+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/state.py", line 215, in parse_ready
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362183+00:00 app[worker.1]:     server = self._add_server_from_data(guild)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362188+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/state.py", line 156, in _add_server_from_data
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362395+00:00 app[worker.1]:     server = Server(**guild)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362396+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/server.py", line 121, in __init__
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362549+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._from_data(kwargs)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362552+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/server.py", line 218, in _from_data
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362764+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._sync(guild)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.362768+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/server.py", line 250, in _sync
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363073+00:00 app[worker.1]:     channel = Channel(server=self, **c)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363111+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/channel.py", line 89, in __init__
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363350+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._update(**kwargs)
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363387+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/discord/channel.py", line 116, in _update
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363608+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._permission_overwrites.append(Overwrites(**overridden))
2020-07-23T13:08:49.363655+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'.
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027848/discord-py-glitch-or-random-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keywor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Glitch or random error: TypeError: \_\_new\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny\_new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027848/discord-py-glitch-or-random-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keywor)

Comment: No, that did not help at all, I tried the update via command `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py` but still the same issue!

Comment: Try writing `pip unstall -U discord`