# How do I make sure that heroku is always using the latest version of a library?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I have a Python Discord bot that has stopped running, I think due to heroku using an out of date discord.py library.

How do I make sure that heroku updates to use the latest libraries, does this happen automatically? How do I also check what version of a library heroku is using?

I have the discord.py library in my requirements.txt file. From reading this answer on stack overflow, I believe that my error is caused by the out of date library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029386/8495863

Comment: There should be a `Pipfile.lock` file that locks your project to specific versions of your dependencies. Make sure it's in Git.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you explain to a novice programmer how I would use that to make sure the libraries are automatically up to date? 

I don't want to lock my project to specific versions, I want it to update automatically to the latest version. In my example, the issue is caused by the library version not being compatible with the latest API, I believe.

Comment: You'd be replacing one problem for another by automating that (you'd no longer have out-of-date libraries, but your code might not work with the updated set). Set yourself a regular patch/update cycle and stick to it - once a quarter, perhaps.