# My discord bot just broke and i have no idea why (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot for my server, and just today it broke randomly, giving this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 359, in <module>
    bot.run("BOT-TOKEN")
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 585, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 463, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
    guild._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 296, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 323, in _sync
    self._add_channel(TextChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 131, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\allis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

I couldn't really decipher it and i'm really confused because it worked fine yesterday. Here is some of my bot's code:

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
owner = "my discord name was here"
client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix="$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)
message_counter = 0
warn_count = 0
poll_count1 = 0
poll_count2 = 0
mute_time = 0
afk = False
i=0
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx, time, *, pollques):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    if int(time) < 2880:
        timecounter = 0
        await ctx.send("A new poll has been opened!")
        await ctx.send("'{}' What do you think? React with :turtle: for option one, and :red_car: for option two. This poll will be active for {} mins".format(pollques, time))
        @bot.event
        async def wait_for_reaction(ctx, reaction: discord.Emoji):
            if reaction.emoji == ":turtle:":
                poll_count1 + 1
            if reaction.emoji == ":red_car:":
                poll_count2 + 1
        while timecounter <= int(time):
            timecounter += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            if timecounter == int(time):
                if poll_count1 < poll_count2:
                    await ctx.send("(Poll) Turtle wins!")
                else:
                    await ctx.send("(Poll) Red car wins!")
                    break
    else:
        await ctx.send(":x: (Poll) That time is too long! Must be under 2 days (2,880 minutes)!")
        

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def cc(ctx, limit1: int):
    channel = ctx.channel
    message = discord.Message
    messages = await channel.history(limit=limit1+1).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        await message.delete()

#mod/admin commands commands

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    try:
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()
        channel = await member.create_dm()
        await channel.send("You have been warned by a staff member, Reason: '{}'. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice.".format(reason))
        await ctx.send("Member warned.")
        print("{} was warned for {}".format(member, reason))
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. User may have blocked the bot.")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def alert(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    try:
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Alert!", color=0xff0000)
        embed.add_field(name="A staff member sent an alert!", value=message)
        embed.add_field(name="Triggered by:", value="{}".format(ctx.message.author))
        await channel.send("", embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(":white_check_mark: Message sent successfully!")
        
    except Exception:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error!")
        embed.add_field(name=":x: An error has occured!", value="Please contact wolverhulk13.")
        await ctx.send("", embed=embed)
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, message_days, *, reason: str):
    try:
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("THE BAN HAMMER HAS BEEN EPICALLY SLAMMED ON {} FOR {}!!! fs in the chat.".format(member, reason))
        await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Ban unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def sban(ctx, member: discord.Member, message_days, *, reason: str):
    try:
        await author.send("You were silently banned from the server. Appeal at wolverhulk@voyagerfamily.com (my email).".format(member, reason))
        await ctx.guild.ban(member)
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Ban unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    await ctx.send("{}'s ban has been lifted! Can I get a $celebrate?".format(member))
    await member.unban(member)
    
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def sunban(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await author.send("You were silently unbanned. Have fun!".format(member))
    await member.unban(member)
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, mins: int):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    global mute_time
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    try:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(":mute: {} muted for {} mins :mute:".format(member, mins))
        while mute_time <= int(mins):
            mute_time += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            if mute_time == int(mins):
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(":microphone2: {} has been unmuted. :microphone2:".format(member))
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Mute unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def stempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, mins: int):
    global mute_time
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    try:
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("You were muted for {} mins.".format(mins))
        await member.add_roles(role)
        while mute_time <= int(mins):
            mute_time += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            if mute_time == int(mins):
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                await author.send("Your were unmuted.")
        
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Mute unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    try:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(":microphone2: {} has been unmuted. :microphone2:".format(member))
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Mute unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def sunmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    try:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        await member.send("You were unmuted.")
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send(":x: Error. Mute unsuccesful. Check spelling?")
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(":mute: {} has been muted. :mute:".format(member))
    
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def smute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(694578104798150717)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await member.send("You were muted. Please appeal in #appeal or wait out your punishment.")
    
    
        

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Grape Gang")
async def gg(ctx):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    await ctx.send(":grapes: Grape Gang :grapes:")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message1):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    ch = await member.create_dm()
    await ch.send("From {}: {}".format(ctx.author,message1))
    await ctx.send(":white_check_mark: Message sent!")



#error handler

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):

    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send(":x: You do not have the required role to use this command!")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":x: You do not have sufficient permission settings to use this command!")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(":x: That command doesn't exist! You may have typed it wrong, try again. Use $help for more information")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":x: I'm missing the permissions to use this command!")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(":x: You missed an argument! For help do $help [command].")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(":x: Wrong value type!")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await ctx.send(":x: This command has been disabled!")
        print(error)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        await ctx.send(":x: This command can not be used inside private messages!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(":x: An unknown error has occured, please contact @wolverhulk13")
        print(error)
        
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def multiping(ctx, member: discord.Member, times:int, *, message):
    global i
    while i < times and times <= 10000:
        await ctx.send("{} {}".format(message, member.mention))
        i += 1
    if times > 10000:
        await ctx.send(":x: You are not permitted to execute this command that many times!")
    enter code here

my run token was here
```

Could someone please help me fix it? Ive been googling for a while and cant find anything on SO or any websites.

Comment: Hello! Since you said you googled: I really don't intend to be condescending by saying that, but I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027848/discord-py-glitch-or-random-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keywor) along with several other relevant pages as top results when I googled `discord "typeerror: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'"`, so as recommendation for the future: The best way to google such issues is to copy the exact message, put it in doublequotes (!), and add a relevant keyword for context (`discord` in this case).

Comment: Note that in Python, the most relevant error message is at the _bottom_ of the stack that is printed. Maybe this was also the reason why you were unable to google it. So again please don't get me wrong here, I'm trying to help you with finding solutions to this sort of problem more effectively next time. 

Comment: Thanks for the help, ill try to remember this in the future. I looked at the mentioned post, and I have tried using the pip install command and it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall multiple times. Am I doing it wrong? This is the command i'm using: "python3 -m pip install -U discord.py"

Comment: What platform are you on? What version of `discord.py` is installed after you updated it (you can add `print(discord.__version__)` to your code to find out)? According to [the corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5109#issuecomment-662274010), it was fixed in version 1.3.4.

Comment: Turns out when i try to check my version, it sayds Unable to Initialize device PRN.
I assume this has something to do with PATH?

Comment: Nvm I noticed now based on your paths that the platform is Windows, of course. I'm sorry but I have no idea about this new error, it sounds as if it is trying to access a file with the name `PRN` or `PRN.something`, which is a reserved filename in Windows. (With the risk of using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut - I would probably run the whole thing in Linux at that point, using the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://pbpython.com/wsl-python.html)... but I'm sure there is an easier solution, I just don't know which.)