# Problem importing yarl or discord.py on python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, python-import, discord.py

I recently updated discord.py due to an error outlined [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027848/discord-py-glitch-or-random-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keywor) and after updating it I can no longer import it.

Running `import discord` brings up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 34, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import BaseConnector as BaseConnector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 30, in <module>
    from yarl import URL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._url import URL, cache_clear, cache_configure, cache_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 56, in <module>
    @rewrite_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 132, in URL
    _QUERY_PART_QUOTER = _Quoter(safe="?/:@", qs=True, requote=False)
  File "yarl/_quoting.pyx", line 192, in yarl._quoting._Quoter.__init__
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requote'
```

The last thing on the list was yarl, so I tried an `import yarl` and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._url import URL, cache_clear, cache_configure, cache_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 56, in <module>
    @rewrite_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 132, in URL
    _QUERY_PART_QUOTER = _Quoter(safe="?/:@", qs=True, requote=False)
  File "yarl/_quoting.pyx", line 192, in yarl._quoting._Quoter.__init__
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requote'
```

The version of python is 3.6.8. I've also tried this on a different machine with 3.6.9 and got the same error. I've tried this on a machine with 3.7.7 and everything loaded normally, but I do not have the ability to upgrade python to 3.7 on this machine and so would like to get it to work on 3.6.

Comment: Same problem, just started yesterday

Comment: I also have the same issue!

Comment: github.com/aio-libs/yarl/issues/485 it appears like this is being tracked in the yarl project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading `pip` did not help me.

Forcing the reinstall of `yarl` as shown by @Orangutan did not help me.

However, the following did the trick:

```
mkdir ~/backup
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl* ~/backup/
pip3 install yarl --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: A new version was released so this should no longer be required (standard pip update), if you do for some reason need to continue using yarl 1.5.0, this seems to be a consistent fix

Answer (score 4):

Updating to yarl 1.5.1 should fix this. The [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/issues/485) suggests it was an issue with internal C code being published.

- [Changelog](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/blob/aa14d56c6f2e6bcd45353e2757a9c6d4ba3f292e/CHANGES.rst#151-2020-08-01)
- [PyPI Page](https://pypi.org/project/yarl/1.5.1/)
- [Fixing PR](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/pull/489)
- [GitHub Release](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/releases/tag/v1.5.1)
- [v1.5.0...v1.5.1 diff](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/compare/v1.5.0...v1.5.1)