# Discord.py Traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

I have added the code which I am using to create a Bot in Discord. I have debugged one error already and now I got another error, which I am unable to understand.

The code is as follows:

````
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(':help'):
        msg = 'Hello! I am Pytho Memer, a meme bot, at your service. You can make me get some nice memes for you.' \
              'You can use the following command for it:' \
              '' \
              '```:meme```' \
              '' \
              'This command will generate a meme for you.' \
              'Hope you will enjoy this. :)'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


client.run(TOKEN)
````

But I have a TraceBack as follows:

```
  File "C:/Users/Bhavyadeep Yadav/Desktop/Python Projects/Pytho Memer/bot_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 491, in start
    yield from self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 448, in connect
    yield from self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 431, in poll_event
    yield from self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 390, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 509, in parse_guild_create
    server = self._get_create_server(data)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 483, in _get_create_server
    server._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\server.py", line 218, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\server.py", line 250, in _sync
    channel = Channel(server=self, **c)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._update(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 116, in _update
    self._permission_overwrites.append(Overwrites(**overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<ConnectionState._delay_ready() running at C:\Users\Bhavyadeep Yadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py:173> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0309F6B0>()]>>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me with how to tackle this. The Type Error is kind of too difficult for me to understand.
I am not that good in Python so I can't debug it myself.
Hope you might help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Glitch or random error: TypeError: \_\_new\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny\_new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027848/discord-py-glitch-or-random-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keywor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed months ago, update your discord.py